# Is there any way to pass the $scope.variable into the $http.post ? issue # in payload my variable are not posting

Tags: angularjs, variables, scope

In HTML i have some customer registration fields

```
<input type="text" ng-model="customer.fname">
<input type="text" ng-model="customer.lname">
<input type="text" ng-model="customer.username">
```

My angular controller code

```
    var customerInformation = $scope.customer;

    customerInformation = JSON.stringify($scope.customer);
    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'person/registrationCustomer',
        data: customerInformation,
        timeout: 4000
    })
        .then(function (success) {

        }, function (error) {


        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var customerInformation = $scope.customer;

$http.post('person/registrationCustomer',customerInformation)
    .then(function (success) {

    }, function (error) {


    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your data should be mapped to an object, have a look:

```
var dataObj = {
    customerInformations : $scope.customer;
};  


$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'person/registrationCustomer',
    data: dataObj,
    timeout: 4000
})
```